Not fail if resource already exists
Same as other infra as code, i was expecting after a deployment, my stack to either skip or update the resources that are listed there, but I'm getting a weird "already exists" error.
    const baseName = "some_constant_name";
    const repository = new Repository(this, `${baseName}Repository`, {
      repositoryName: snakeCase(`${baseName}Repository`),
    });

    const logGroup = new LogGroup(this, `${baseName}LogGroup`, {
      retention: 90,
      logGroupName: '/aws/ecs/graphql-api',
    });


Though the problem is that they have the same name, is there a way I can skip those items created?
The error message is:

GraphqlApiDevStack failed: Error: The stack named GraphqlApiDevStack failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup' with identifier '{"/properties/LogGroupName":"/aws/ecs/graphql-api"}' already exists."


The simple answer here is "no".

whats the best way then?

The best way is not to assign physical names to your resources and let CloudFormation generate them for you, preventing any possible collisions. Or just remove the existing resource.

IMO, leaving loggroup names to be auto-generated is not the best way, because you end up with duplicated logGroups when the stack is redeployed and later on it's a mess to find the right one.

If you set your logGroup name to a fixed value (i.e. not generated by CloudFormation), then you will get that error when you destroy the stack, because the default RemovalPolicy is set to RETAIN.
You have two choices:

set the removal policy to DESTROY
or quickly delete the group manually before re-deployment of the stack, e.g. via CLI:

aws logs delete-log-group --log-group-name ...

